# Generate admissible permutations

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist

I would like to generate all possible permutations of a set List but the permutations are not all eligible. The permutations are as combinations of   subsets' permutations of the set List.

For example we have the following list composed of two subsets: List = {(1,2), (3,4)};
admissible permutations are : 1234/1243/2134/2143/3412/4312/3421/4321
the following permutations are not admissible: 1423/3142/1324/1342/2431/2341 / ....

I have generated all possible permutations but not those admissible.

```
static void permute(ArrayList<Integer> arr, int k){
  for(int i = k; i < arr.size(); i++){
      java.util.Collections.swap(arr, i, k);
      permute(arr, k+1);
      java.util.Collections.swap(arr, k, i);
  }
  if (k == arr.size() -1){
      System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(arr.toArray()));
  }
```

}

I'm really need this code to calculate the value of Owen (game theory). Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue here is that you are getting the possible permutations of the first array, then the second array and concatenating them, what you need to do is do the same thing you did in your code, then make a new 2darray that has the first value of the first array, and the first value of the second array, then the second value of the second array, then the second value of the first array. so you find the permutations possible with {(1,2), (3,4)} using your current technique, then you find the permutations possible with {(1,3), (2,4)} and {(1,4), (2,4)} and so on.

If you have more then 2 lists then a helpful source is http://www.programcreek.com/2013/02/leetcode-permutations-java/
it explains the process, and has code that illustrates.

Comment: Hi, I can't resolve the problem. I have more than two arrays, so I can't write a generic solution. Please help me, I 'm really need the solution. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I refined the answer. take a look.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have 8 admissible permutations, the elements of the symmetry group of a complete binary tree with 4 leaves, [S2 wreath S2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wreath_product). If that is what you want in general, you can generate all of them by looping through the permutations of the first level, and then for each of these, loop through all of the choices for the permutations of the second level, fixing the permutation of the first level.

If n is very small, you can generate all permutations, then reject those that do not produce a consistent permutation of the first level.